# Can I use mdf primer on exterior wood?

Tags: painting

I am repainting my front door. I have an unopened can of MDF primer, can I use this prior to painting?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do the instructions on the can say?

Comment: The fact that your primer is for MDF only tells us that it's solvent-based and not water based. It says nothing about suitability for your door.

Comment: Painter here. I've never heard of MDF primer.  Is it a brand? :)   I've also never heard of a primer intended for one *specific* type of wood.  Maybe that's how you *think of it*, but maybe you can tell us about what it actually *is*, or at least what it thinks it is.  You can [edit] your question to improve or add info.

Comment: I hadn't heard of it either. It's just solvent/oil-based primer labeled for use on MDF. Water-based primer is likely to swell the MDF fibers.

Comment: Water-based anything is likely to swell any wood's fibers.  Suddenly my affinity for oil-based KILZ makes more sense.  (though for real wood jobs I always go straight to 2-part epoxy marine primer, best wood primer on earth. But I would not put $90/gal marine epoxy on MDF...)